# How to access parent class member function's input parameters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

I want to access function's input parameter 'current_dir' in this ES6 class, but it does not work. What's wrong?

```
class helloClass {

  expand_dir(current_dir) {
    let defer = $helloAjaxCall();

    defer.done(function(data) {
       console.log(current_dir);
    }.bind(this));
  }
}
```

Comment: `log.console` should probably be the other way around

Comment: What you’ve demonstrated should absolutely work.